# Installing cardano-node: pathspec 'null'

Tags: cardano-node, git

I'm following the instructions [here](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node) for both Linux and Mac M2 chip...

Both installs are stopped at this instruction, with the following error:

> ~cardano-source/cardano-node$ git checkout $(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/input-output-hk/cardano-node/releases/latest | jq -r .tag_name)
> error: pathspec 'null' did not match any files(s) known to git
> ~cardano-source/cardano-node$

Since I don't see any similar queztions here at Stack... I'm guessing I did something wrong, but I don't see it.  Even after going through all the steps again.  Can someone with better eyes than me provide some insight?

Comment: This was the previous command >git fetch --all --recurse-submodules --tags

Answer (score 0):

At any rate, `git describe --tags` seems to match the api doc at the url given; and `git describe --tags | git checkout` did it in both the mac and linux boxes.